# React input textfield should not vertically align and not wrap

Tags: css, reactjs, textfield

I have a react front end that has input textfields. The text within these inputs will not start at the top of the input field and wrap appropriately.

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #2F363A;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input {
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
  text-rendering: auto;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<input
  placeholder="Enter key results..."
  className="medium"
  id="last"
/>
```

Comment: Instead of input why you not try textarea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```